# nginx php-fpm uploaded files have nginx ownership after executing move uploaded file

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, files, upload

I have a problem with php 5.3.6 using PHP-FPM and file uploads.

My Nginx runs as user nginx
PHP-FPM uses pools configured for each vhost. For example a user: test group : test runs one pool.

When the php file uploads to temp file it is owned by user test.
After move_uploaded_file is executed by php script it is owned by nginx :/.

I do not know if the change in ownership to web server is the correct behaviour. Is there a way in PHP to change the ownership back to the user I want? (Without going the php chown way as it requires root privileges)

Answer (score 1):

AFter a fresh day's start and some excessive lat workout I finally sat down to resolve this once again.
I found that I had pointed by nginx to the wrong pool. I did it because the session path was giving permission denied errors. this other pool was user 'nginx' default pool. So I fixed the session save path issue by editing php.ini and poiniting it to /tmp. Thats the only way it worked, the default values don;t work on centos. viz /tmp/session for more than one pool. So again back to problem THe new settings witht he right pool works fine.

noob win!